# Turn the table not function PIVOT MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

[image]

wish your support to rotate the table without the function PIVOT

[image]

this is the result.

`it is only separated by 1,2,3,4 with if value by id`

Comment: Why should PIVOT not be used?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Maybe because PIVOT not exists in MySQL?

Comment: If `califica` values list is static 1..4 then use conditional aggregation.

Comment: it is right doesn't exist in MySQL, Yes califica is the value 1,2,3,4

Comment: See also `GROUP_CONCAT()`.